# org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize

Tags: serialization, redis, spring-session

I am working on a Spring boot project. I need to implement Spring Boot session using Redis db server. It works fine for the Session details.

But I need to put some meta-data information into HashMaps and store them in Sessions and store them in Redis. When I go for this, I am getting the SerializationException. Few lines of the same are given below:

"org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:161)\r\n\tat org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisSessionRepository.java:298)\r\n\tat org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository$RedisSession.save(RedisSessionRepository.java:276)\r\n\tat org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository.save(RedisSessionRepository.java:125)\r\n\tat org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository.save(RedisSessionRepository.java:42)

I have already implemented Serializable of the beans/information of the metadata stored in Spring session.

Even then it shows the above error.

I have added the following Configuration file for the RedisTemplate bean.

`@Configuration  public class RedisConfiguration extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration{ @Bean public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) { RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>(); template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory); template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()); template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()); template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()); template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()); return template; }`

Adding this also has no effect on getting the Exception.

What should I do the returning redisTemplate bean in my application/controller class? Provide me the possible help.